# Unexpected appended output from sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I am trying to edit a couple of text files in Newick format. For the purpose of this, there is a species name (which I want to keep) connected by an underscore to a gene name (which I want to remove).

So from something like:

```
(Species_A_Some_Gene_Code:0.1,Species_B_GeneCode:0.2,(Species_C_Code:0.3,Species_D_Some_code:0.4):0.5);
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B:0.2,(Species_C:0.3,Species_D:0.4):0.5);
```

My current approach of using `sed` in `bash`. I'm trying to match something including the species name, up to the first colon (`:`), but discard stuff between the species name and the colon.

```
for i in Species_A Species_B Species_C Species_D; do 
sed -i 's;\('"$i"'\)[^:]*\(:.*\);\1\2;p' "/directory/*.txt"
done
```

What I get is... odd? Hard to tell because the actual result is bigger, but it looks a bit like:

```
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B_GeneCode:0.2,(Species_C_Code:0.3,Species_D_Some_code:0.4):0.5);
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B:0.2,(Species_C_Code:0.3,Species_D_Some_code:0.4):0.5);
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B:0.2,(Species_C:0.3,Species_D_Some_code:0.4):0.5);
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B:0.2,(Species_C_Code:0.3,Species_D:0.4):0.5);
```

As if the result gets appended rather than replacing the old one. I am guessing it might have something to do with the second group that `sed` is trying to match, but I'm not sure. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: You have the `p` at the end of the `s///` command, it tells `sed` to print that line if it matched the replacement pattern. But the default behaviour is to print any lines anyway, so you get them doubled. I'm not sure why you'd get a bunch of different lines though, since the patterns with `Species_A` to `Species_D` should all match.

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you! Well spotted - I removed the 'p' and it looks fine now. I guess I had it because of testing small pieces of input beforehand (piped in with 'echo' as opposed to from a file). Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be `sed`? How about this `awk`:

```
awk '
NR==1   {m = split ($0, T)
     next
    }
    {for (i=m; i; i--) sub(T[i] "[^:]*", T[i])
    }
1
' - file <<< "Species_A Species_B Species_C Species_D"
(Species_A:0.1,Species_B:0.2,(Species_C:0.3,Species_D:0.4):0.5);
```

It `split`s the species read from a "here string" into the `T` array, and then for each line read from the file, replaces each string consisting of the respective `T` element plus any non-":" character by the `T` element, effectively removing the non-":" stuff.